# Using Jsoup to extract text from HTML, but returned left and right quotation mark chars

Tags: java, html, string, character-encoding, jsoup

So I used Jsoup to extract some text from an html snippit, shown here:

```
<font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">BHI Finance LLC (“BHI Finance”)</font>
```

Notice the left and right quotation marks. I store this text in a String in Java here:

```
Element firstEntry = row.select("td").first();
String toAdd = firstEntry.select("font").text();
```

String toAdd gets printed as BHI Finance LLC (?BHI Finance?)

The two question mark chars when casted to an int are 147 and 148 respectively which I found to be left and right quotation marks on (certain?) html char encodings. My question is how do I make it so Jsoup parses left and right quotation marks as just regualar ascii quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like a parsing problem. More likely, whatever you're using to display the parsed content doesn't correctly display those characters.

The easiest is probably to just replace them:

```
toAdd = toAdd.replaceAll("[“”]", "\"");
```

Comment: Hi! So I'm just using System.out.println(toAdd) and I tried this and it didn't work, its still giving me character codes 147 and 148 (which dont actually exist in standard ascii)